# How to send a midi file as a Message Attachment

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I made my bot generate a random midi file, I just need to know how to send it onto discord

```
var write = new MidiWriter.Writer([track]);
message.channel.send(new Discord.Attachment(write.dataUri()))
  .catch(console.error);
```

The error it gives me is:

```
{ [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Users\bossay\Desktop\Botz\CropBot\data:audio\midi;base64,TVRoZAAAAAYAAAABAIBNVHJrAAAASgCQA0CEAIADQACQAEAAgABAAJACQIQAgAJAAJADQACAA0AAkANAhACAA0AAkABAggCAAEAAkABAhACAAEAAkAJAggCAAkAA\y8A']
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'stat',
  path:
   'C:\\Users\\bossay\\Desktop\\Botz\\CropBot\\data:audio\\midi;base64,TVRoZAAAAAYAAAABAIBNVHJrAAAASgCQA0CEAIADQACQAEAAgABAAJACQIQAgAJAAJADQACAA0AAkANAhACAA0AAkABAggCAAEAAkABAhACAAEAAkAJAggCAAkAA\\y8A' }
```

Comment: thanks for fixing my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to assume you are using the [midi-writer-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/midi-writer-js) npm module here.

The [Discord.Attachment](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Attachment) does not accept a data uri, you want to pass a buffer instead.
(Also to not send a `file.jpg` you need to set a file name)

To get such a buffer you can pass the Uint8Array retrieved via [Writer#buildFile](https://www.npmjs.com/package/midi-writer-js#midiwriterwritertracks) to [Buffer.from](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_from_buffer).

Putting all of it together could look like this.

```js
var write = new MidiWriter.Writer([track]);
var buffer = Buffer.from(write.buildFile())
message.channel.send(new Discord.Attachment(buffer, 'file.midi'))
    .catch(console.error);
```